# .htaccess Rewriting Multiple Folders

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wasn't sure how to title this and after a lot of research I'm not finding what I need. Hopefully I can explain this well enough!

My URL structure is handled by `index.php`, which takes the entire URL, breaks apart the /'s and organizes them into an array to see where to forward the user to. As an example [here](http://www.mysite.com/?cat1/subcat1/subcat2/page1).

Now the problem with most guides on `htaccess` is that they give examples based on using known query strings rather than pre-set query strings I'm taking the URL and breaking it up, so it can be infinitely long. As [another example](http://www.mysite.com/?cat1/subcat1/subcat2/subcat3/subcat4/page1), we could add new sub-cats to the above.

And this would still forward properly (basically the script automatically takes in the first item to pull the template, then the last item to use as the article id to pull. Anything in between can also have its own template, and if not, uses a generic one that displays all items within its sub-category).

I'm attempting to use `htaccess` to take everything after `mysite.com/` and pull it in as a single query to pass to index. Ex. (using the above):

**URL Input**: `www.mysite.com/?cat1/subcat1/subcat2/subcat3/subcat4/page1`

**Query passed to index.php**: `cat1/subcat1/subcat2/subcat3/subcat4/page1`

Now the goal here is to ultimately remove the "?" after `mysite.com/` to clean up the URL so it's more like `mysite.com/cat1/subcat1`.

As for my research, I've only been able to find things based on known query strings (such as `?cat1=&subcat1=`), but I need it to be dynamic as different things will have different depths. This is where my index side comes in , but I can't figure out how to get `htaccess` to forward the entire query as one string for analyzing.

Any help would be much appreciated, and hopefully this was clear enough to understand. If there are any questions, feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I've gotten it somewhat working.
Here's the code I'm using now:

```
RewriteRule  ([^/]+) index.php?%{REQUEST_URI}%{QUERY_STRING} [nc]
```

This works for the most part, however it always sets array items as follows:

0 => empty
1 => index.php

2 => (first part of query, ex. "cat1")

I've tried altering the above code in many ways but I guess my lack of knowledge is holding me back from being able to properly get it set up (more or less what's in array space 3 should be in space 0, and the current 0/1 (empty/index.php) should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about 
`RewriteRule (.+) index.php?url=$1 [nc]`

Than in your index.php you will have

```
<?php    echo $_GET['url']; ?>
    output: cat1/subcat1/subcat2/subcat3/subcat4/page1
```

and should manually split your categories.

Comment: (Sorry for the messed up formatting... can't figure out how to format these posts here, lol).

When I added both of those codes, the following is what I get as the "url" GET's response when using mysite.com: "index.php"

When using a deeper URL such as mysite.com/test, I get the same response ("index.php") but it also changes the browser's URL to mysite.com/test/?url=test

Comment: I guess that there is some additional redirection in your system. Do you use some framework or you build everything on your own?
And I have an error in the redirect - a (dot) should do the job.

Comment: It's custom. What I did for that is just $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] and then output that array (I have other handling as well, but even that first step isn't coming out right). When I'm not using htaccess I can use site.com/?folder/folder2/folder3, etc. and it will always output the array properly.

Comment: Just noticed you updated the code above. I tried that and it comes up with "index.php" as the only output regardless of the URL input... Tried it with my script first to no avail, and then with a new fresh PHP document with nothing but the output. Both have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how to solve your problem but the issue you are talking about is called url rewriting.

It's a common way to organize things in PHP and content management systems. A framework. The framework is called MVC or model view control.

I know that in cake-php, a specific framework/csm, it is entirely possible to turn off url rewriting. Though if you do this, I think it worsens search engine optimization.